# How can I check if the current user is accessing his/her own user page?

Tags: theming, 6, users

I would like to print something in `page-user.tpl.php` only when the current user is accessing his own user page.
(any URL starting with `/user/%uid/` but when %uid/ is the user id of the current logged in user)

For example, printing something like "Your are viewing your own user page now." in `page-user.tpl.php`

How can I make this condtion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two paths a user could be visiting their own page: "user" and "user/UID" where their UID matches.

There is a global variable [$user](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/user/6) that stores the currently logged in user.

So in the [variable preprocessor for the template](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430) you can determine whether or not a user is on their own user page and save it to a variable that you can reference in the template file, like below.
Note the use of `$variables['logged_in']`, which is an available variable as listed in the [page.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/6) documentation.

```
/**
 * Override or insert variables into the page templates.
 *
 * @param $variables
 *   An array of variables to pass to the theme template.
 */
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // If we are on the 'user' page or a sub-page of it.
  if (arg(0) == 'user') {
    $variables['own_account'] = FALSE;
    // If we are on 'user' and are logged in then we are on our own user page.
    if (!arg(1) && $variables['logged_in']) {
      $variables['own_account'] = TRUE;
    }
    // If we are on 'user/UID' then check against the current user.
    else if (is_numeric(arg(1)) && !arg(2)) {
      global $user;
      if ($user->uid == arg(1)) {
        $variables['own_account'] = TRUE;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use the variable `$own_profile` in your `page-user.tpl.php` template, which in this case might look something like this:

```
<?php if ($own_account): ?>
  <div class="own-account-msg">
    Here is some markup for the message a user sees when they are on their own account page.
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! Only one thing is that it works only on "user" and "user/UID" (I think that's what you have mentioned about the user page.) But is there anyway to make it to work also on "user/UID/edit" or other custom view pages like "user/UID/my_custom_view_page" ? I mean, all the pages that page-user.tpl.php is applied to.

Comment: Yep, you can remove the  " && !arg(2)" part from the else if to get all sub pages of the user account.